# Elisp: How to search a wordlist and copy the results to another buffer?

Tags: search, copy, buffer, elisp

I have a wordlist

```
dempron {hic, haec, hoc, huius, huic, hunc, hanc, hac, hi, hae, horum, harum, his, hos, has}
```

I have a xml-kind-of text

```
<p>Hoc templum magnum est.</p>
<p>Templa Romanorum magna sunt.</p>
<p>Claudia haec templa in foro videt.</p>
```

I would like to search the wordlist "dempron" and copy the sentences that have words from the wordlist to a buffer called *results*.

Comment: Any attempts of your own on this problem? Stackoverflow is for specific programming problems and not a site where people write code for free...

Comment: I did not have the intention of abusing Stackoverflow. I hope that
others will benefit from charliegreen's code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Simon Fromme, but hopefully this will get you started. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
(defconst dempron
  '("hic" "haec" "hoc" "huius" "huic" "hunc" "hanc" "hac" "hi" "hae" "horum"
    "harum" "his" "hos" "has"))

(defun dempron-search ()
  "A function to naively search for sentences in XML <p> tags
containing words from `dempron'. Run this in the buffer you want
to search, and it will search from POINT onwards, writing results
to a buffer called 'results'."
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)

  (while (not (eobp)) ;; while we're not at the end of the buffer
    (let ((cur-line   ;; get the current line as a string
           (buffer-substring-no-properties
            (progn (beginning-of-line) (point))
            (progn (end-of-line) (point)))))

      ;; See if our current line is in a <p> tag (and run `string-match' so we
      ;; can extract the sentence with `match-string')
      (if (string-match "^<p>\\(.*\\)</p>$" cur-line)
      (progn
        ;; then extract the actual sentence with `match-string'
        (setq cur-line (match-string 1 cur-line))

        ;; For each word in our sentence... (split on whitespace and
        ;; anything the sentence is likely to end with)
        (dolist (word (split-string cur-line "[[:space:].?!\"]+"))
          ;; `downcase' to make our search case-insensitive
          (if (member (downcase word) dempron)
              ;; We have a match! Temporarily switch to the
              ;; results buffer and write the sentence
              (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "results")
                (insert cur-line "\n")))))))
    (forward-line 1))) ;; Move to the next line
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your treasure trove of code. It works great
and I definitely get started.